# Implicit intent failed to send to my other Activity

Tags: android

I have 2 activities: Create/Receive.

Create class:

```
public void onSendMessage(View view){
    EditText msgText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    String msg = msgText.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
    intent.setType("text/plain");

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Receive class:

```
public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_message);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String msgText = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TEXT);
    TextView msgView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.receiveText);
    msgView.setText(msgText);
}
```

The manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".ReceiveMessage">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Debugging into it reveals that the msg gets created in first activity, but somehow I got null when it gets to the Receive activity.

Any tips what went wrong?

Edit:
Okay, just to be more clearer on what I hope to achieve. I want my Activity to be able to send the text both to the Messaging app AND my second Activity.

Sending this:

```
// This works for sending to Messaging app, but my second Activity can't read this
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);

// This works for sending to my second Activity, but the Messaging app can't read this
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_TEXT", msg);
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes from this line

```
public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "message";`
```

in your `Receive` class.

The `Intent` class already defines an `EXTRA_TEXT` constant [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_TEXT).

Comment: Hey, thanks. Now that you said that, I just realized I was being dumb :) A year out of OOP really slows my brain down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Use the Same keyName** while passing data through Intent and at the time of Receiving..

Define Constant Variable somewhere or create one class for constants and then use it as common keyName.

InSender FirstActivity

```
intent.putExtra("keyName", msg);
startActivity(intent);
```

InReceiver SecondActivity

```
String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("keyName");
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Because writing it as:

    intent.putExtra("EXTRA_TEXT", msg);
    String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_TEXT");

works for sending the message to my ReceiveActivity. But now when I try to send the message to the Messaging (Android SMS app), it breaks.

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with syntax, but I couldn't figure out how/why...